# Deactivate read-only & non-realtime mode in firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Suddenly I am facing a issue that, "Read-only and non-realtime mode activated in the data viewer to improve browser performance" in firebase. This message is showing on Real Time Database. After that database performance slow down the platforms of my mobile App . I want to get out of this mode to previous one.

Comment: *firebaser here* "After that database performance slow down the platforms of my mobile App" The read-only mode of the Firebase console has no effect on access to the database through the API. If you're having performance problems, they more likely come from the amount of data you have, but not from the mode-switch of the console.

Comment: If you're still having performance problems when accessing the database through the API, please open a new question with the [minimal, complete information that is needed for any of us to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).